# replace content of a div with other content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I a web page i have only a div

```
<div id="example">codehtml1</div>
```

Clicking a button in this webpage  if is content of `<div id="example">` is codehtml1
i want change content in codehtml2 if the content of `<div id="example">` is codehtml2  i want change in codehtml1

this is what i'm tryng:

```
<div id="example">
    codehtml1</div>
<button class="test">click to change</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').click(function() {                           
        var lookcontent2 = 'codehtml2';        
        $('#example').html(lookcontent2);        
    });
});
```

Any help?
thanks

Comment: so the problem is you want it to swap back to codehtml1?

Comment: yes riclicking i want rechange to codehtml1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to get the text of `#example` div, and using if condition to match the text as following code, Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.test').click(function() { 
    var content = $('#example').text();
    if(content=="codehtml2")
    {
        $('#example').text('codehtml1');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#example').text('codehtml2');
    }       
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an if statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lookcontent2 = 'codehtml2';
    var lookcontent1 = 'codehtml1';
    $('.test').click(function() {                           
      if ($('#example').html() == lookcontent1) {
        $('#example').html(lookcontent2); 
      }
      if ($('#example').html() == lookcontent2) {
        $('#example').html(lookcontent1); 
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you could just set up a conditional to check and toggle between the two: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/nt1nxwxx/)

```
$('.test').click(function(){    
    var lookcontent1 = 'codehtml1';
    var lookcontent2 = 'codehtml2';        
    if($('#example').html() == lookcontent1){
        $('#example').html(lookcontent2);      
    } else {
        $('#example').html(lookcontent1);      
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the content, you can have two elements where one is visible, and just switch them. That way you don't need to keep the content in the JavaScript code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').click(function() {
        $('#example1,#example2').toggle();        
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="example1">codehtml1</div>
<div id="example2" style="display:none">codehtml2</div>
<button class="test">click to change</button>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok ok but i don't want place in html code <div id="example2"  however thanks for answer i have resolved with other solutions thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

I would this with keeping track of state instead of doing the string compression of the div content.

```
<div id="example">
codehtml1</div>
<button class="test">click to change</button>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').click((function (currentState) { 
    return function() {                           
      var lookcontent2 = 'codehtml2';
      var lookcontent1 = 'sometstuff';
      if (currentState = 1) {
        currentState = 2;
        $('#example').html(lookcontent2);
      } else {
        currentState = 1;
        $('#example').html(lookcontent1);
      }        
    });
  })(1)
});
```